# React Router Cannot resolve module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

Getting this error...

EDIT routes.js to reflect changes

> ERROR in ./app/config/routes.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-rounter' in /Users/sam/Desktop/battle/app/config
>    @ ./app/config/routes.js 2:19-43

I have webpack and react - react-dom - react-router - babel, etc all installed into my npm packages.  When I run npm start I get the above error.  Here are my package.json / webpack config / router.js files

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "battle",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "production": "webpack -p",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "Sam Schaefer <smmschaefer@gmail.com>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config**

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './app/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: "index_bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

**routes.js**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;
var Main = require('../components/Main');
var Home = require('../components/Home');

var routes = (
    <Router>
        <Route path='/' component={Main}>
            <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: I see you've edited you question, did my suggestion solve the error message you were receiving?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error points to issue:

> ERROR in ./app/config/routes.js Module not found: Error: Cannot
>   resolve module 'react-**rou*n*ter**' in /Users/sam/Desktop/battle/app/config
>   @ ./app/config/routes.js 2:19-43

In your *routes.js* file:

```
react-rounter
         ^--- this is probasbly the issue.
```

Shouldn't that be 'react-**router**'?  Correct the typo in your routes.js file and you should be good to go.

Comment: Ah! Nice catch.  Fixed but still getting an error about getCurrentLocation not being caught, but you fixed me posting problem.  THANK YOU =)

Comment: Glad I could help.  It's always worth checking if the error makes sense first :).

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue migrating from `react-router` 3.x to 4.x

I fixed the issue by installing two missing dependencies that are added in 4.x

```
npm install react-router-dom
npm install react-router-config
```

See the `react-router` [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/CHANGES.md#v400-beta6).

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",

Changed to

    "react-router-config": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.1",

Answer (score 7):

The Error is:

> Module not found: Can't resolve '**react-router**' in 'E:\Redux\media-library\src'.

Solution is:

Run the below command in your directory.

> $ npm install --save react-router-dom

Answer (score 0):

fixed the issue by installing the missing dependencies:

```
npm i react-router-dom

npm i react-router-config

npm i --save react-router-dom
```

Answer (score 0):

First, uninstall reach router, then

Install
`npm install @reach/router`

Import
`import { Router, Link } from "@reach/router"`

Use

```
<Router>
    <Home path="/" />
</Router>
```

See the official site https://reach.tech/router/